# Obj-C: dispatch_async crashes without NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, crash, dispatch-async

for some reason i have a dispatch_async thread, and it crashes unless i have a NSLog() method executed in front of it. the block runs a method that retrieves a username from a database.

crash:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    user_web_communicator *usrWeb = [[user_web_communicator alloc]init];
    NSString *author = [usrWeb getUsernameFromID:author_string];
    [_author_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",author]];
});
```

working:

```
NSLog(@"Fetching author for id: %@",author_string);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    user_web_communicator *usrWeb = [[user_web_communicator alloc]init];
    NSString *author = [usrWeb getUsernameFromID:author_string];
    [_author_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",author]];
});
```

error

> ```
> 2013-08-19 13:56:06.149 Poll Me[4995:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{
> ```
>
> Rows:     AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.minX == 10 + 1*0x827b8d0.marker +
>   -1*0x8281210.marker + 0.5*0x8281260.marker    AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.minY == 27.5 + -1*0x827b910.marker +
>   -1*0x82812a0.marker + 0.5*0x82812e0.marker + 0.5*0x82823f0.marker + -0.5*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Height  Regular_Cell:0x827a400.Height == 56 + 1*0x82823f0.marker    Regular_Cell:0x827a400.Width == 320 +
>   1*0x8281ee0.marker    Regular_Cell:0x827a400.minX == 0 +
>   1*0x8281740.marker + -0.5*0x8281ee0.marker
>     Regular_Cell:0x827a400.minY == 46 + 1*0x8281b30.marker +
>   -0.5*0x82823f0.marker     UILabel:0x827a8e0.Width == 0 + 1*0x827b730.marker + 1*0x827b790.marker + -1*0x827b7d0.marker +
>   1*UILabel:0x827adc0.Width     UILabel:0x827a8e0.minX == 18 +
>   1*0x827b7d0.marker + 1*0x827b8d0.marker + -1*0x8281210.marker +
>   0.5*0x8281260.marker + 1*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Width   UILabel:0x827a8e0.minY == 19.5 + -1*0x827b810.marker +
>   1*0x827b890.marker + -1*0x827b910.marker + -1*0x82812a0.marker +
>   0.5*0x82812e0.marker + 0.5*0x82823f0.marker + 0.5*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Height + -1*UILabel:0x827a8e0.Height + -1*UILabel:0x827b140.Height     UILabel:0x827adc0.minX == 18 + 1*0x827b730.marker + 1*0x827b8d0.marker + -1*0x8281210.marker +
>   0.5*0x8281260.marker + 1*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Width   UILabel:0x827adc0.minY == 20.5 + 1*0x827b6f0.marker +
>   -1*0x82812a0.marker + 0.5*0x82812e0.marker    UILabel:0x827b140.minX == 18 + 1*0x827b850.marker + 1*0x827b8d0.marker + -1*0x8281210.marker +
>   0.5*0x8281260.marker + 1*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Width   UILabel:0x827b140.minY == 27.5 + 1*0x827b890.marker +
>   -1*0x827b910.marker + -1*0x82812a0.marker + 0.5*0x82812e0.marker + 0.5*0x82823f0.marker + 0.5*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Height + -1*UILabel:0x827b140.Height   UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.Height == 55 +
>   1*0x82812e0.marker    UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.Width == 300
>   + 1*0x8281260.marker  UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.minX == 0 + 1*0x8281210.marker + -0.5*0x8281260.marker
>     UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.minY == 0.5 + 1*0x82812a0.marker
>   + -0.5*0x82812e0.marker   objective == <> + <750:-1>*0x8280fc0.negError + <250:-1>*0x8280fc0.posErrorMarker + <750:-1>*0x8281030.negError + <250:-1>*0x8281030.posErrorMarker
>
> Constraints:          Marker:0x8281210.marker
>             Marker:0x8281260.marker
>          Marker:0x82812a0.marker (Integralization adjustment:0.5)         Marker:0x82812e0.marker
>          Marker:0x8281740.marker
>           Marker:0x8281b30.marker
>             Marker:0x8280fc0.posErrorMarker
>             Marker:0x8281030.posErrorMarker
>           Marker:0x827b6f0.marker
>             Marker:0x827b730.marker
>            Marker:0x827b790.marker
>             Marker:0x827b7d0.marker
>            Marker:0x827b810.marker
>             Marker:0x827b850.marker
>           Marker:0x827b890.marker
>           Marker:0x827b8d0.marker
>          Marker:0x827b910.marker
>           Marker:0x8281ee0.marker
>            Marker:0x82823f0.marker }: internal
>   error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head
>   0x8280fc0.negError, which should never happen.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x195d012 0x166ae7e 0x195cdeb 0xefef89 0xf01fcf 0xf025c7 0xf0d58f 0xf0d6d4 0x7d860a 0x7e02af 0x7e03be
>   0x2e7601 0x49484e 0x354ced 0x2e940c 0x354a7b 0x359919 0x3599cf
>   0x3421bb 0x352b4b 0x2ef2dd 0x167e6b0 0x17dfc0 0x17233c 0x172150
>   0xf00bc 0xf1227 0xf18e2 0x1925afe 0x1925a3d 0x19037c2 0x1902f44
>   0x1902e1b 0x29be7e3 0x29be668 0x29effc 0x1e5ed 0x1d75) 2013-08-19
>   13:56:06.149 Poll Me[4995:4f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{ Rows:
>     AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.minX == 10 + 1*0x827b8d0.marker +
>   -1*0x8281210.marker + 0.5*0x8281260.marker    AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.minY == 27.5 + -1*0x827b910.marker +
>   -1*0x82812a0.marker + 0.5*0x82812e0.marker + 0.5*0x82823f0.marker + -0.5*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Height  Regular_Cell:0x827a400.Height == 56 + 1*0x82823f0.marker    Regular_Cell:0x827a400.Width == 320 +
>   1*0x8281ee0.marker    Regular_Cell:0x827a400.minX == 0 +
>   1*0x8281740.marker + -0.5*0x8281ee0.marker
>     Regular_Cell:0x827a400.minY == 46 + 1*0x8281b30.marker +
>   -0.5*0x82823f0.marker     UILabel:0x827a8e0.Width == 0 + 1*0x827b730.marker + 1*0x827b790.marker + -1*0x827b7d0.marker +
>   1*UILabel:0x827adc0.Width     UILabel:0x827a8e0.minX == 18 +
>   1*0x827b7d0.marker + 1*0x827b8d0.marker + -1*0x8281210.marker +
>   0.5*0x8281260.marker + 1*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Width   UILabel:0x827a8e0.minY == 19.5 + -1*0x827b810.marker +
>   1*0x827b890.marker + -1*0x827b910.marker + -1*0x82812a0.marker +
>   0.5*0x82812e0.marker + 0.5*0x82823f0.marker + 0.5*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Height + -1*UILabel:0x827a8e0.Height + -1*UILabel:0x827b140.Height     UILabel:0x827adc0.minX == 18 + 1*0x827b730.marker + 1*0x827b8d0.marker + -1*0x8281210.marker +
>   0.5*0x8281260.marker + 1*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Width   UILabel:0x827adc0.minY == 20.5 + 1*0x827b6f0.marker +
>   -1*0x82812a0.marker + 0.5*0x82812e0.marker    UILabel:0x827b140.minX == 18 + 1*0x827b850.marker + 1*0x827b8d0.marker + -1*0x8281210.marker +
>   0.5*0x8281260.marker + 1*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Width   UILabel:0x827b140.minY == 27.5 + 1*0x827b890.marker +
>   -1*0x827b910.marker + -1*0x82812a0.marker + 0.5*0x82812e0.marker + 0.5*0x82823f0.marker + 0.5*AsyncImageView:0x827aa00.Height + -1*UILabel:0x827b140.Height   UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.Height == 55 +
>   1*0x82812e0.marker    UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.Width == 300
>   + 1*0x8281260.marker  UITableViewCellContentView:0xlibc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception827a560.minX == 0 +
>   1*0x8281210.marker + -0.5*0x8281260.marker
>     UITableViewCellContentView:0x827a560.minY == 0.5 + 1*0x82812a0.marker
>   + -0.5*0x82812e0.marker   objective == <> + <750:-1>*0x8280fc0.negError + <250:-1>*0x8280fc0.posErrorMarker + <750:-1>*0x8281030.negError + <250:-1>*0x8281030.posErrorMarker
>
> Constraints:          Marker:0x8281210.marker
>             Marker:0x8281260.marker
>          Marker:0x82812a0.marker (Integralization adjustment:0.5)         Marker:0x82812e0.marker
>          Marker:0x8281740.marker           Marker:0x8281b30.marker
>             Marker:0x8280fc0.posErrorMarker
>             Marker:0x8281030.posErrorMarker
>           Marker:0x827b6f0.marker
>             Marker:0x827b730.marker
>            Marker:0x827b790.marker
>             Marker:0x827b7d0.marker
>            Marker:0x827b810.marker
>             Marker:0x827b850.marker
>           Marker:0x827b890.marker
>           Marker:0x827b8d0.marker
>          Marker:0x827b910.marker
>           Marker:0x8281ee0.marker
>            Marker:0x82823f0.marker }: internal
>   error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head
>   0x8280fc0.negError, which should never happen.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x195d012 0x166ae7e 0x195cdeb 0xefef89 0xf01fcf 0xf020d3 0x7d86dc 0x7d9280 0x7dd4a3 0x3f7e3c 0x3f8022
>   0x3f8064 0x2f33b 0x277553f 0x2787014 0x27782e8 0x2778450 0x92710e72
>   0x926f8d2a) (lldb)

can you please tell me why this could be happening? i dont want to keep the NSLog() there because it runs it several times and gets in the way when trying to read output. Thank you in advance =)

Comment: It may be easier to answer if you put the actual error messages in your question :)

Comment: updating now... sorry, error message is very long

Comment: In addition to my answer below, show how you are defining/setting author_string. There could be something else to it.

Comment: author_string is just an integer id appended onto the url that communicates with a PHP document retrieving the username. Your answer worked great, it was just a thread issue. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to set the text property of a label in a background thread, or any other UI changes for that matter. Since it is undefined behavior I can not explain why it works with the `NSLog` but you need to dispatch setting the label's text to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    user_web_communicator *usrWeb = [[user_web_communicator alloc]init];
    NSString *author = [usrWeb getUsernameFromID:author_string];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_author_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",author]];
    })
});
```

Comment: `dispatch_sync` may work in this example, but in general be careful not to create deadlocks where two blocks and their threads wait for each other.